# SSH key added in github with read/write, but still getting permission denied

Tags: git

So I've been using GitHub for years without any issues. Today I just ran into the first one. I created a new account, created a new repository, and I cloned and committed to the repository. Basically I have content in my GitHub repository at the moment.

However, just now I tried to use `git commit -am "Updated."` and just ran a simple `git push origin master` to commit my changes, and I ran into this error:

```
[user:.../scripts/ptscripts]$ git push origin master                                                              12:01PM/05.13
ERROR: Permission to my-github-user/ptscripts.git denied to [obfuscated user].
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. My public SSH key is added into my GitHub account and it shows Read/Write. The [obfuscated user]. however, belongs to another GitHub user account so I'm not quite sure why it's trying to use an old user account.

The only thing that I did recently was change the permissions of `~/.config` from root to my user account to suppress a warning about permission denied. Other than that, I haven't changed anything.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I must have had the same SSH key in two different GitHub accounts or something - not sure yet. This is what I did to fix it, even though it may not be the correct or easiest way:

1. Listed the keys cached by `ssh-agent` by running `ssh-add -l`
2. Removed all of the keys by running `ssh-add -d /path/to/key` for each key
3. Killed both `ssh-agent` services that were running with `pgrep ssh-agent | xargs kill`
4. Restarted `ssh-agent` with `eval $(ssh-agent)`
5. Re-added the key using `ssh-add /path/to/key`

After running `git push origin master` again, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you did not change the secret SSH key for github.com.
GitHub distinctes users by what SSH key is used.

`~/.ssh/config` is convenient to change key.
My config for github.com is this.

```
Host github.com
  user git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/set0gut1.key
#  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/old-account.key
```